# Access relative path from eclipse-plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, uri, relative-path

Does anyone know how to get a file with uri from a self-made Eclipse Plug-in?

Absolute paths would be no problem:

```
URI.createFileURI("C:/Users/hp/workspace(dke)/SMartGen/StarSchema.profile.uml");
```

But how do I access local resources relatively?

```
URI.createFileURI("jar:file:/%ECLIPSE_HOME%/plugins/SMartGen.jar!StarSchema.profile.uml");
```

doesn't work this way....

Happy for every answer.

lg martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [FileLocator](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/FileLocator.html).

Example:

```
URL iconUrl = FileLocator.find(Platform.getBundle("myBundle"), new Path("icons/someIcon.png"), null);
```

This will get the URL of a file "someIcon.png" that is located in the "icons" folder in the bundle "myBundle".

Comment: but now i got another problem with changing 
java.net.URL to 
org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI
url.toUri() and util.URI is in some kind not the same
I will post another question for it.

Comment: If you really need an absolute URL to the file, use `FileLocator.resolve(url)` on the resulting URL from `FileLocator.find`.

Answer (score 0):

For getting a resource out of eclipse, you can use `org.osgi.framework.Bundle.getEntry(String)`.  That returns a standard `java.net.URL`, which can also be used to get the `InputStream` for consumption.  It has the advantage of not caring if your plugin is in directory form, jar form, or in your workspace.

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(MyClass.class);
URL url = bundle.getEntry("StarSchema.profile.uml");
```

URL has a handy `toURI()` method as well.