# Referencing a local folder in an osgi plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle

I want to reference a local resource folder (not the files in it), with the name 'test', of my osgi plugin. I found these two examples ([1](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6261759/1121737)) on the internet:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("de.vogella.example.readfile");
URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry("files/test.txt");
File file = null;
try {
    file = new File(FileLocator.resolve(fileURL).toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

This one doesn't work for me, because the FileLocator object isn't resolved (nothing is recommended by eclipse to resolve this).

The second snippet:

```
URL iconUrl = FileLocator.find(Platform.getBundle("myBundle"), new Path("icons/someIcon.png"))
```

This one doesn't work for me, because the Platfrom, FileLocator and Path objects arent resolved.

Is there a different way I could go about referencing a local folder than the two ways described above? The folder is located one level below root (same as the libs folder for storing jar files).

Comment: Those examples are for Eclipse plug-ins only - is this an Eclipse plug-in or a generic OSGi plug-in?

Comment: I believe it is a generic osgi bundle, since it has the Activator.class.

Comment: Eclipse plugins can have an Activator. The question is are you intending to run this as an Eclipse plugin or are you going to use some other OSGi system.

Comment: I intend to run it with the Equinox OSGi framework.

Answer (score 4):

A resource in bundle does not have to be located on the file system. The URL has a special URL scheme to reflect this. It is just bad practice to assume you can convert a URL to a file in any way. A URL can be turned into a InputStream ... that is the only guarantee you get.

So you should take the input stream and copy it to a temporary file. However, generally you can use the Input Stream directly in most cases.

In OSGi, you can, however, traverse the folders inside the bundle. Look at [Bundle.findEntries](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#findEntries(java.lang.String,+java.lang.String,+boolean)).